# Convert Data table to Frequency table correctly with weights

Tags: r, datatable, frequency

Here's the problem

With this data table

`dt <- data.table(
Type=c("E", "E", "B", "B","B","B","C",NA), 
ID=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6),
Frequency=c(17, 6, 3,8, 12,8,9,10))`

The summarytools package frequency function gives the following result:

`summarytools::freq(dt,weights=dt$Frequency)`

`.     Freq   % Valid   % Valid Cum.   % Total   % Total Cum.`

---

```
    B   31.00     49.21          49.21     42.47          42.47
    C    9.00     14.29          63.49     12.33          54.79
    E   23.00     36.51         100.00     31.51          86.30
 <NA>   10.00                              13.70         100.00
Total   73.00    100.00         100.00    100.00         100.00
```

## This takes weights in account and also entire data table but

## is not able to give me percentages which include the #NA counts

(Only gives valid percentage counts)

The function 'freq' from package 'questionr' gives that.
See additional "%" column, before "val%" column

`questionr::freq(dt$Type)`

`.   n      %       val%`

`B    4    50.0    57.1

 C    1   12.5    14.3

 E    2   25.0    28.6

 NA   1   12.5      NA

 4 rows`

But this second function does not accept

1.weights (column Frequency in my example)

2.Entire data table ( rather than specifying individual columns)

Maybe a better function is out there or even some deft lines of code to add 
"%" functionality in the first function? Thanks!

Comment: I get a more complex result (a list with three elements) from the first code. Furthermore there is a colum: "% Total" which appears to already have what you are requesting. Perhaps you are using an out-of-date version of the package?

Comment: Thanks you are correct. Please post as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a more complex result (a list with three elements) from the first code. Furthermore there is a column: "% Total" which appears to already have what you are requesting. Perhaps you are using an out-of-date version of the package?